# Canva: Is there a fonts cheat sheet?

Tags: fonts, canva

One simply can't scroll through all the thousands of fonts in Canva, but if you have an idea in mind then that's what you have to do to find one that works for your design. Someone somewhere must have made a series of graphics that show all the font names written in the font they name. I'm sure a lot of Canva users would pay for this document.